# Adding Bottom Line Border To A TextView - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

What is the best way to add a bottom line border to a `TextView` with a dynamic height?

I tried this:

```
func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
   let border = CALayer()
   border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
   border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - width, 
   self.frame.size.width, width)
   self.layer.addSublayer(border)
   self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

I thought a lot about my original solution.

If you are subclassing `UITextView` to add a bottom line, then the bottom line had better be a subview of the text view itself, rather than its super view's.

And finally, I figure out one solution that can add bottom line as a subview of `TextView` itself and the bottom line will not move when the user scrolls the text of `TextView`. In your view controller, you can also change the frame of `TextView` dynamically, and the bottom line will also stick to the the bottom.

Here is the reference code:

```
import UIKit

class TextView: UITextView {

    var border: UIView
    var originalBorderFrame: CGRect
    var originalInsetBottom: CGFloat

    deinit {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset")
    }

    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            border.frame = CGRectMake(0, frame.height+contentOffset.y-border.frame.height, frame.width, border.frame.height)
            originalBorderFrame  = CGRectMake(0, frame.height-border.frame.height, frame.width, border.frame.height);
        }
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if keyPath == "contentOffset" {
            border.frame = CGRectOffset(originalBorderFrame, 0, contentOffset.y)
        }
    }

    func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
        border.backgroundColor = color
        border.frame = CGRectMake(0, frame.height+contentOffset.y-width, self.frame.width, width)
        originalBorderFrame = CGRectMake(0, frame.height-width, self.frame.width, width)
        textContainerInset.bottom = originalInsetBottom+width
    }
}
```

**Note:** Since I used to write code in Objective-C, I am not familiar with Swift. The code above is only for your reference (though I have tested the corresponding Objective-C code, and it works as expected):

- As you can see, there is no initialisation code. I have tried to write such code, but it always shows an error and I still have no idea about that. Just make sure to add the below code to your `TextView` initialisation code:

  ```
  border = UIView()
  addSubview(border)
  originalInsetBottom = textContainerInset.bottom
  addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: .New, context: nil)
  ```
- I am not familiar with the concept of optional value, wrap, unwrap... So you should add `?`, `!` to the code if needed.

**Original answer:**

Does `self` in your code mean `TextView`?

If so, when you add `border` as a sublayer of the `TextView`, the `border` will move up and down when the user scrolls the text of `TextView`.

Try to add `border` as a sublayer of `TextView`'s super view rather than `TextView` itself.

Here is the code (Note that I change `border` from `CALayer` to `UIView`):

```
func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
     let border = UIView()
     border.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y+self.frame.height-width, textView.frame.width, width)
     border.backgroundColor = color
     self.superview!.insertSubview(border, aboveSubview: textView)
 }
```

Here is the capture:

[image]

PS. I suggest you to change the second paramter name from width to height since width is ambiguous in this context.

Comment: your solution is perfect expect for one bug, i have a dynamic expanding textview so every time the textview is expanded or shrank the border position get missed and will reposition correctly when i type again. what might the reason be?

Comment: @AliAlebrahim Can you tell more about 'dynamic expanding'? Does that mean you will change the frame.height of `TextView`?

Comment: yes the height of the textview changes during runtime.

Comment: @CokileCeoi can you please share objective-c code ?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4 Version**

```
func addBottomBorderWithColor() {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yourTextArea.frame.height - 1, width: yourTextArea.frame.width, height: 1)
    yourTextArea.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: The border is wrong when the user scroll with a lot of text

Answer (score 2):

It works better with following line:
border.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

```
extension UITextView { 
    func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, height: CGFloat) {
        let border = UIView()
        border.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        border.frame = CGRect(self.frame.origin.x,    
        self.frame.origin.y+self.frame.height-height, self.frame.width, height)
        border.backgroundColor = color
        self.superview!.insertSubview(border, aboveSubview: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this method needs be called AFTER the textView added to the super view, otherwise it'll crash on the last line...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried other answers, they are either hard to implement, or come with bugs, however, I've found a **simple and perhaps the best way** to achieve this:

Just add a `UIView` next to your `UITextView`, with a height of 1 (or maybe 2 of your choice), set up the constraints, make sure the `UIView` is above the `UITextView`.

All of this can be achieved in storyboard so I'm not giving code here, since this `UIView` can be replaced with an UIImageView, you can add mustache to your `UITextView` if you wish

:)

Answer (score 0):

Set the mask to bounds to be false then only it show the bounds of the line that  you want to show..

Comment: add the line as subview to your superview

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code it may helps you**

```
func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, yourTextview.frame.origin.y+yourTextview.frame.size.height+1 , width, 1)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it's easier to just keep things a little more independent of one another.

```
UIImageView * border = [UIImageView new];
border.frame = CGRectMake(0,y,100,0.5f);
border.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];
[self.view addSubview:border];
```

Comment: This question is tagged "swift". Your solution may have value, but is not written in the language requested by OP, so it's off-topic. Please provide an answer in Swift. Thank you.