# Why is CALayer not being added to UITextView

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a text view and I am attempting to add a line underneath it. I am trying to accomplish this with a CALayer, however it is not showing up in the textView. I would appreciate it if someone could help me. The code is below.

```
let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#CC0000").cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: messageField.frame.height - 3, width: messageField.frame.width, height: 3)
        messageField.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326249/adding-bottom-line-border-to-a-textview-ios/51523141

Answer (score 0):

In my test app, I just tried this:

```
    let messageField = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 40, width: view.frame.width - 60, height: 40))
    var border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
     border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: messageField.frame.height - 3, width: messageField.frame.width, height: 3)
     messageField.layer.addSublayer(border)

    view.addSubview(messageField)
```

And it worked fine.  Weird but fine. The color showed up no problem, but it scrolls along with the text view.  But that might be what you want.  I tried it with different heights for the message field too.  I couldn't get it to not show.

If you want it to work and have the line not scroll with the text, try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38327895/793607

Comment: I have dynamic textview. Could that be a reason why this is not working.

Comment: dumb question-- are you sure that your hex color converter works?  Also, you could play with the frame of the sublayer, make it CGRect(x: 0, y: 3, width: messageField.frame.width, height: 3). That would put it definitely within the text field, even if you had weird sizing happening.

Comment: The hex color converter definitely works because I have used in other places of the app. I changed the frame and it is still not showing up. I tried the exact same code on a completely normal textview as well and it was not working. The only difference between your implementation and mine is that I used constraints to position my textview.

Comment: this is incredibly wrong. in iOS when you add layers, you must resize them in **layoutSubviews**, which exists for that purpose